# UWP CommandBar as resource

Tags: xaml, uwp, commandbar

I got a `CommandBar` i'd like to use for all my pages within the app.
When creating a new command bar using the 'New' button in the properties window and converting the new value to a resource using 'Convert to New Resource' (the resource is placed in a resource dictionary) VS creates
the following xaml:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="BottomBar" />
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Resource dict.:

```
<CommandBar x:Key="BottomBar" />
```

Now when launching the application an unhandled exception with the message 'The parameter is incorrect' is thrown (inner exception: 'Value does not fall within the expected range'). Is that intended behaviour or is there a workaround (except for using a style)?

Comment: I'm also stuck here. The full exception says `Exception {System.Exception: The request is not supported. CommandBars can only be set in Page.BottomAppBar.}` Creating CommandBar in code behind and assigning it to BottomAppBar works just fine.